# Where can I get an 'unit and integration plan checklist' template?

Tags: manual-testing, agile-testing, regression-testing, test-planning

I’m working on a new project and I need a checklist template. Can anyone share a template so I can use it?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own checklist and update it based on learnings.

There is no unit-test and integration plan checklist template.

Maybe these unit-test guidelines is a start: http://geosoft.no/development/unittesting.html

Answer (score 0):

We create a test plan in software testing services to define its scope, strategy, testing methodologies, areas that would be covered / not to be covered under testing etc. In unit testing we test all the individual units or components of the application whereas in Integration testing we combine these individual units or components and validate their behavior after integrating.

Both Unit Testing as well as Integration testing are a part of Test Plan checklist. So, there exist no separate checklist for them.

Below is the links for further details regarding Test Plan and common templates used while creating any Test Plan :

http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/test-plan/

http://www.guru99.com/what-everybody-ought-to-know-about-test-planing.html

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-plan-sample-softwaretesting-and-quality-assurance-templates/